# 1 of 2 monitors turned of but it turns on after logout

Tags: display, monitor

It's not a big issue, just trying to find an explanation and possibly a remedy.
Obviously I don't want to pull any plugs.
So.. For whatever reason I sometimes turn off one monitor in Settings->Display. Not cut the power, otherwise the cursor isn't restricted on the remaining monitor. Everything works as expected unless I logout, for example to enable a changed setting that requires a logout/login.
As soon as the login screen appears, the turned-off monitor turns on and after correct password validation, the monitor turns off again.
BTW: same thing happens during boot time: both monitors are powered-on but as soon as the user session starts, the monitor turns off.
So I conclude the monitor setting is user-bound, right?
Is there a way to make it a system-wide setting??
PS. I don't want to be editing any files.

Answer (score 0):

> So I conclude the monitor setting is user-bound, right?
>   Sure.

If you use `gdm` as login manager, you can copy your current display settings like this:

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm/.config/monitors.xml
```

Comment: I use `lightdm`, so your suggestion does not apply. And as said, I do not want to modify config files as I am not resolving an error but, let's call it, a beautification issue.